# Jenkins - Mail configuration for Hotmail

Tags: macos, email, jenkins, continuous-integration, hotmail

I don't know what am I doing wrong, I'm searching the net for hours. Anyways, here is my e-mail setup for Jenkins. I'm not able to send any mails. When I click "Test Configuration", I get the following error.

I changed the STMP Port to 25 and still get the same error.

[image]

And btw I typed `telnet smtp.live.com 587` to my console ant the output was:

```
Trying 65.55.163.152...
Connected to smtp.glbdns2.microsoft.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 BLU437-SMTP76.smtp.hotmail.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 8.0.9200.16384 ready at  Thu, 2 Jul 2015 04:31:09 -0700 
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

What am I missing? What is the correct configuration? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The traceback looks awfully similar to the one in the [Jenkins SMTP TSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370327/jenkins-smtp-tsl) question, some of those answers might help.

The bounty doesn't allow flagging as duplicate...

Comment: None of the answers seem to solve his problem, neither did mine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution on gmail:

Set SMTP server as `smtp.gmail.com` and port as `25`

This should work.