# Jenkins smtp error 550 relay not permitted

Tags: email, jenkins, smtp

I am running Jenkins version 1.651.2 with the email plugin version 1.17. I have an account on a company smtp server I am trying to connect to. The credentials check out, and I am connecting on port 587 with ssl off (connection is encrypted), encoding UTF-8. The jenkins instance i from a server hosted on EMR. There is no firewall on the Jenkins instance, and amazon security group allows all outgoing traffic. I have the settings working perfectly on another Jenkins instance. I can ping the smtp server from amazon. I tried the following solution [Jenkins SMTP TSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370327/jenkins-smtp-tsl) to no avail. I keep on getting the following error:

```
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 relay not permitted
```

Is this likely an error on the jenkins side, or smtp server?

I have absolutely no idea how to solve this. Help anyone?

Comment: 550 relay not permitted means your SMTP server is refusing to act as a relay between the sender and the recipient.  Often, it means you have failed to configure it to recognize the sender as a local, authorized user. Not a programming problem anyway; voting to close as off-topic for Stack Overflow.