# TLSv1.2 in Jenkins for SMTP

Tags: email, jenkins, smtp, tls1.2, amazon-ses

We are using SMTP protocol in Jenkins to send mails. Under Extended Email Notification, we have configured as below.

We are using SMTP port as 465 and we have checked mark SSL.

Now, there is a need to upgrade to TLS 1.2 or above as per the below error.

*Error sending to the following VALID addresses: XXXXXXXX.com XXXXXX.com
SendFailedException message: 554 Access denied: Amazon SES no longer supports TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 connections. You must update your client to use TLS version 1.2 or above. To learn more and to update your client, see https://go.aws/3AUlVSb. For further assistance, contact AWS support*

Could you please let us know how to do that and what port needs to be used? Our SMTP server has been configured in AWS SES.

We tried unchecking SSL but it didn't work still and expecting to receive mails.

Answer (score 2):

To address the issue of upgrading to TLS 1.2 for SMTP in Jenkins, particularly when using [AWS SES (Simple Email Service)](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/), you will need to make sure your Jenkins setup and the underlying Java environment support TLS 1.2.

```bash
[ Jenkins Server ] --> SMTP (TLS 1.2) --> [ AWS SES ]
```

Jenkins itself relies on the underlying Java version for network protocols, including TLS. Make sure you are running a Java version that supports TLS 1.2 by default. Java 8 and later versions should support it.

For Jenkins to use TLS 1.2, you might need to explicitly specify the use of TLS 1.2 in the Java arguments if you are using an older version of Java. You can do this by adding the following JVM option: `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` (as [seen here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/issues/634#issuecomment-368841075)). Or (as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39136802/6309)):

```
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2"
```

For AWS SES, when using TLS 1.2, you can still use port **465** for SMTP over SSL/TLS. Alternatively, you can use port **587** for SMTP with STARTTLS. Both should be compatible with TLS 1.2.
Make sure the "SSL" option is checked if you are using port 465. If you decide to use port 587, you should configure Jenkins to start the connection in plaintext and then upgrade to TLS using `STARTTLS`.
As [noted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74135579/6309), the E-mail Extension plugin has support for SMTP over TLS and the additional "TLS" configuration checkbox, revealed by clicking on the Advanced button, since v2.83 released in May 2021.

---

> We are running Jenkins on the Jenkins container, when we checked for the jenkinsfile, it was not present at `etc/sysconfig/jenkins` and `/etc/default/jenkins`, and we tried in other locations as well, but we did not get it. We tried "`openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -tls1_2`" command to make sure the Jenkins container is supporting TLS 1.2 and, as expected, it was supported.
>
> We are unable to find the Jenkins file to change the configuration in the Jenkins container in this case where I need to alter the configuration that enables TLS 1.2.

When running Jenkins in a Docker container, the configuration is typically managed differently than in a traditional installation.
In a Dockerized environment, environment variables and Dockerfile instructions are commonly used to set configuration options instead of modifying files like `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` or `/etc/default/jenkins`.

You can pass Java options directly to your Jenkins container via environment variables. That is done by setting the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable when you run your container. If you want to enforce TLS 1.2, you can add `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` to `JAVA_OPTS`, as [Olakunle Abiola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23310241/olakunle-abiola) noted in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77954308/6309).

```bash
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 \
  -e JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2" \
  jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Since you have already verified TLS 1.2 support using `openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -tls1_2`, it is clear that the underlying system and Java environment are capable of supporting TLS 1.2. By configuring the `JAVA_OPTS` as shown above, you instruct the Jenkins instance running within the container to utilize TLS 1.2 for its operations, including SMTP communications.

Regarding the Jenkinsfile not being found at `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` or `/etc/default/jenkins`, the Jenkinsfile is typically part of a project's source code repository rather than the Jenkins system configuration. It defines a pipeline and is checked into source control, which Jenkins retrieves as part of a job. System configurations for Jenkins, especially in a containerized setup, are managed through environment variables and the initial Jenkins setup wizard rather than through a Jenkinsfile.

---

If you are building your own Jenkins Docker image, you can specify the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable in your Dockerfile. That makes sure any container spawned from this image will automatically have these options applied.

But, as you [commented before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77947221/jenkins-configuration-file-in-jenkins-docker-container#comment137430190_77954308):

> We are not creating jenkins with container newly, already we created jenkins with container many years back so we cannot create so easily, what I want here the jenkins is running on docker container from long so I want to update "JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2" in the existing one. Please suggest where to update or in which file to update, i did not find the etc/sysconfig/jenkins and etc/sysconfig/jenkins in this paths

Updating the `JAVA_OPTS` to include `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` in an existing Jenkins Docker container setup, without the ability to modify it via the usual system paths like `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`, requires a different approach. Since Docker containers are designed to be ephemeral, configuration changes like this are typically done *outside* of the container filesystem.

If your container is managed by a Docker Compose file or a Docker orchestration tool like Kubernetes, you can add or modify the environment variable there.

In your `docker-compose.yml` file, you can specify environment variables under the `environment` key for your Jenkins service:

```yaml
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

After updating the file, redeploy your service: `docker-compose up -d`

If Jenkins is deployed in Kubernetes, you can set environment variables in your deployment configuration:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jenkins
        image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
        env:
        - name: JAVA_OPTS
          value: "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2"
```

Apply the changes with `kubectl apply -f your-deployment-file.yaml`.

Directly modifying a running container's environment variables is not straightforward and generally not recommended, as changes will be lost if the container restarts: `docker exec -it <container_id_or_name> /bin/bash` + `xport JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2"`.
That method is not persistent and would need to be reapplied if the container restarts.

For a permanent solution, you would typically need to recreate the container with the new environment variable. You can do this without losing your Jenkins data if you have correctly set up volumes for Jenkins data persistence. The general steps would be:

1. Stop the current Jenkins container.
2. Remove the old container (make sure your data is backed up or on a volume).
3. Start a new instance of the Jenkins container with the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable set, as shown in the Docker Run command earlier. Be sure to mount the same volumes to preserve your Jenkins data and configurations.

That approach makes sure the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable is correctly set and persistent across container restarts and redeployments.

---

> We tried with `docker exec -it <container_id_or_name> /bin/bash` + `export JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2"` for temporary, We got below error trying with multiple way.

The issues you get with SMTP configurations in Jenkins when attempting to send emails via AWS SES mean that you need to fine-tune your SMTP settings based on the port and security protocol being used.

When you uncheck "`Use SSL`":

- on port 587, you get `MessagingException message: 220 Ready to start TLS`: the server is ready to start TLS encryption, but the connection might not be properly upgrading to TLS.
  When using port 587, it is important to enable `STARTTLS` rather than `SSL/TLS` directly. Make sure your Jenkins SMTP configuration is set to use STARTTLS. That might involve checking a "`Use TLS`" or "`StartTLS`" option, rather than "`Use SSL`".
- on port 465, you get `Could not connect to SMTP host: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, port: 465`: port 465 is intended for SMTPS (SMTP over SSL) from the outset of the connection. If "`Use SSL`" is unchecked, Jenkins may attempt to connect without the necessary SSL/TLS encryption, leading to a failure. That port should be used with "`Use SSL`" checked/enabled.

When you do check "`Use SSL`" on port 465, you get `MessagingException message: Could not connect to SMTP host: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, port: 465`: that happens if there is a firewall blocking the connection, if the SMTP server details are incorrect, or if there is an issue with the SSL/TLS configuration.
First, verify that the SMTP host and credentials are correct.
Next, make sure there is no firewall or network issue preventing access to AWS SES on port 465.
And, since you are enforcing TLS 1.2 through `JAVA_OPTS`, make sure your Jenkins Java environment and AWS SES are compatible with these settings.

Comment: Hi, We are running jenkins on jenkins conatiner, when we checked for the jenkins file and it is not present at etc/sysconfig/jenkins and /etc/default/jenkins and we tried in other locations as well but we didnot get. We tried "openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -tls1_2" command to make sure jenkins container is supporting TLS 1.2 and as expected it was supporting. 

We are unable to find the jenkins file to change the configuration in jenkins container at this case where i need to change the configuration which enables TLS 1.2

Comment: @Umesh I have edited the answer to address your question.

Comment: We tried with 
docker exec -it <container_id_or_name> /bin/bash + export JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2" for temporary, We got below error trying with multiple way @VonC

Comment: port 587 and unclicked "use SSL"
Sending email to: XYZ.com ABC.com
MessagingException message: 220 Ready to start TLS

Port 465 and unclicked for "use SSL"
Setting In-Reply-To since last build was not successful
Successfully created MimeMessage
Sending email to: XYZ.com ABC.com
Click here to forcibly terminate running steps

Port 465 and clicked for "use SSL"
Adding recipients from trigger recipient list
Successfully created MimeMessage
Sending email to: XYZ.com ABC.com
MessagingException message: Could not connect to SMTP host: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, port: 465

Comment: @Umesh I have edited the answer to address your error messages.