# Jenkins configuration file in jenkins docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, containers, docker-machine, jenkins-cli

The jenkins is running on docker container(jenkins docker) and need to upgrade to TLS 1.2 so I am unable to find the jenkins configuration file in the jenkins container.

I tried with below paths for jenkins configuration file

/etc/sysconfig/jenkins and /etc/default/jenkins

But I didn't get jenkins configuration file

Please help to find the jenkins configuration file path in jenkins container

Comment: Can you check **/var/jenkins_home** as this is the default Jenkins home directory inside docker containers.

Comment: Hi @OlakunleAbiol, thanks for the replay, lot of files are existing in mentioned path but we are not able to see any files with name of "jenkins confirmation". Please could you confirm what will be the name of jenkins confirmation file ??

Comment: Let’s take a step back and analyze the situation. How did you setup Jenkins? Do you have a dockerfile you used in building the container image that you’re running? i.e is it custom?

Comment: I added more details to my answer. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi @OlakunleAbiola, jenkins is running on container and i have attached another ticket url here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77906529/tlsv1-2-in-jenkins-for-smtp and why we are looking for jenkins configuration file. Thanks for your continuous response

Comment: have you tried the steps I specified in my answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77954308/23310241 ?  Also, it helps if your question is in one place(as opposed to separate questions on the same topic).